# terraform destroy manual github action

Tags: github, terraform, continuous-integration, github-actions

I wrote a GitHub CI action to deploy on AWS using terraform.

I wonder if it is possible to implement something similar to GitLab CI and add a step to destroy the infrastructure that is manually triggered like:

```
Staging Destroy:
  stage: Destroy
  script:
    - cd deploy/terraform/
    - terraform init
    - terraform workspace select staging
    - terraform destroy -auto-approve

  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH =~ /^(master|production)$/'
      when: manual
```

Comment: Side note: `terraform destroy` is typically only for individual sandboxes as other environments are actively managed, and the sandbox workflow is normally executed outside of pipelines.

Comment: I have to create 3 workspaces and want Gitlab ci (which already works fine) and GitHub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trigger manually with `workflow_dispatch` and add a conditional to check branch name:

```yaml
name: "Staging Destroy"
on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  destroy:
    if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/master' || github.ref == 'ref/heads/production'
...
```